How to create a generic class extend from a mixin in TypeScript
I'm a new of TypeScript. Now I want to init a object for response data like this:
const auth = new ResponseData<Clazz>();

Here is my mixin BaseResponseHelper
type Constructor<T = object> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export function BaseResponseHelper<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase, options?: ApiPropertyOptions | undefined) {
  class ResponseDTO {
    @ApiProperty({ description: 'Mã lỗi thực hiện API', example: '0000' })
    @IsString()
    error_code!: string;

    @ApiProperty({
      description: 'Nội dung mã lỗi',
      example: '[XXXX]Thực hiện thành công',
    })
    @IsString()
    error_desc!: string;

    @ApiProperty({
      description: 'Trạng thái thực hiện API',
      example: true,
    })
    @IsBoolean()
    success!: boolean;

    @ApiProperty({
      isArray: true,
      type: () => Base,
      example: () => Base,
      description: 'Cấu trúc data trả về',
      ...options,
    })
    @Type(() => Base)
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    data_list!: Array<InstanceType<TBase>>;
  }
  return mixin(ResponseDTO); 
}


I wrote a class like this but it's not working:
export class ResponseData<T> extends BaseResponseHelper(T) {}

How can I pass generic type in ResponseData.ts file?
Thanks guy!
export class ResponseData<T> extends BaseResponseHelper(T) {}


Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] which we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to clearly see what you're seeing without distractions and where the problem is obvious. Right now this is pseudocode (...) and/or refers to private/third-party things (ApiPropertyOptions, mixin) and so we can't easily play around with it. Furthermore you say "it's not working" but not how it's not working or what the problem is.  Please read the guidelines for how to make a [mre] and [edit] accordingly. Good luck!

Regarding the question's wording. A class might apply a mixin, but a class should never be allowed extending a mixin. Being able of actually doing the latter in TS is due to TS-mixins are implemented as classes itself either pure or as ad-hoc created sub-classes (the most common use case). But it's pure inheritance all along, polluting or even breaking the prototype chain. In my opinion TS totally screwed the concept of mixins.

Unfortunately this code doesn't seem to be a [mre] since if I copy and paste it into my IDE I get even more errors than before, none of which you seem to be asking about. Note that ApiPropertyOptions and mixin are still undeclared. Please re-read my first comment and the guidelines for what makes a [mre]. I'll check back if I see an update. Otherwise, good luck!

Have you read this page ?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html
you can use a generic type this way for both base class and extended object:
export class ResponseData<T> extends BaseResponseHelper<T> {}

However, you are using mixin and BaseResponseHelper is a function, meaning at some point you should write something like
class MyBaseClass
const ResponseData = BaseResponseHelper(MyBaseClass, options)

Unless you are trying to use hybrid type
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#hybrid-types
but you may be more explicit with your goal here

Thanks for answer me. I'm a newbie of TS. I want to have correct definition generated. I code like this post: https://www.inextenso.dev/how-to-generate-generic-dtos-with-nestjs-and-swagger
